# Device Admin Receiver not working in few versions

Tags: android, device-admin

I am working on a security app, which protects device from strangers.

In my application, I have a feature that should capture the image from front camera if user tries to unlock device with wrong PIN/Pattern/Password.

I have a code something like this.

```
public class MyAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent, UserHandle user) {


        Log.d("MyTag", "onPasswordFailed called");
        //Code for starting a service for image capture goes here
        .
        .
        .
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

In almost all the versions, I am getting the image captured properly, and the app is working fine.

Issue is: In a few devices the function `onPasswordFailed` is not working.  Device admin is activated properly. I tried disabling it again and re-activating it. I tried restarting the device. But nothing worked. I can see this log in my stacktrace.

```
03-09 12:04:48.078 18491-18491/com.my.pkgname D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED flg=0x10 cmp=com.my.pkgname/.receivers.MyAdminReceiver }, receiver=com.my.pkgname.receivers.MyAdminReceiver@30c2044b
03-09 12:04:48.079 18491-18491/com.my.pkgname D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED flg=0x10 cmp=com.my.pkgname/.receivers.MyAdminReceiver } packageName=com.my.pkgname resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
```

This issue is so far seen in all the devices I could see of Android 6.0 (Marshmallow version) and Android 7.1.1 (Its Motorola device, if that helps).

I have already checked below questions:

- [Android 4.0 Device Admin Receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200023/android-4-0-device-admin-receiver-not-working)
- [Android Device Admin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848155/android-device-admin-not-working)
- [Having trouble receiving ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED and ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED intents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067328/having-trouble-receiving-action-password-succeeded-and-action-password-failed-in)

They are not relevant as my admin.xml file, and Manifest declaration is alright and its working in all other devices with version Android 7, 8, 9.

And I have tested using pattern, valid PIN which is more than minimum length. I have not set other password restrictions at all.

Still I am showing the Manifest part an admin.xml for verifying.

**Manifest declaration:**

```
....
<application>
    ....
    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.MyAdminReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/admin" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    ....
</application>
```

**admin.xml file:**

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <watch-login />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Can someone help with this issue?

Let me know if there is any special permission required / or setting that is mandatory.

P.S: I tested with some changes in code. Same device admin can perform lockNow() function properly when I added necessary policy in admin.xml. So device admin is setup correctly. So what is the issue that `onPasswordFailed` might not be called?

I also tried adding intent filter for `ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED` in manifest. Made no difference.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED" />
    <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can you please give  tested devices name or model? both working and not working.

Comment: not working in Moto E4 (7.1.1). working in redmi note 5 (8.1.0) @VasudevVyas

Comment: Hi Ana, can you share the working code to lock with the device admin? I am working on a lock screen app and facing the issues, my app is not locking and not working so I want to check and compare with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`void onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent, UserHandle user)` only works with Oreo and above.

For backward compatibility, you also need to override `onPasswordFailed(Context context, Intent intent)`. That will make your code work on Nougat and below.